# Multiple custom file input fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I've modified this [example](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/) to better suit my needs in handling multiple custom file uploads on the same page. It also renders the filename or truncates if it is too long for each of the 3 file fields. This solution works well however, I think it could be DRY'd out a lot? This is where I landed:

```
$(document).on('change', '.compliance-guide :file', function() {
  var input = $(this),
      label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
  input.trigger('fileselect', [label]);
});

$(document).on('change', '.compliance-other :file', function() {
  var input = $(this),
      label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
  input.trigger('fileselect', [label]);
});

$(document).on('change', '.agreement-file :file', function() {
  var input = $(this),
      label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
  input.trigger('fileselect', [label]);
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.compliance-guide :file').on('fileselect', function(event, label) {     
        var log = label;       
        if( log.length > 14 ) {
            $('.compliance-guide-name').html(log.substring(0,14)+'...');
        } else {
            $('.compliance-guide-name').html(log);
        }
    });
    $('.compliance-other :file').on('fileselect', function(event, label) {     
        var log = label;       
        if( log.length > 14 ) {
            $('.compliance-other-name').html(log.substring(0,14)+'...');
        } else {
            $('.compliance-other-name').html(log);
        }
    });
    $('.agreement-file :file').on('fileselect', function(event, label) {     
        var log = label;       
        if( log.length > 14 ) {
            $('.agreement-file-name').html(log.substring(0,14)+'...');
        } else {
            $('.agreement-file-name').html(log);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly combine the first 3 handlers into 1, since they do the exact same thing:

```
$(document).on('change', ':file', function () {
  var input = $(this),
      filename = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
  input.trigger('fileselect', [filename]);
});
```

That'll add an event handler to *all* file inputs on the page.

You can simplify the `replace` stuff a bit; there's no need to make backslashes into regular slashes, if you're just going to throw it all away afterward. So it'd be simpler to say

```
input.val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/g, '')
```

i.e. remove everything up-to-and-including the last slash.

Handling the custom `fileselect` event is where you want to limit it to *specific* inputs. However, you can extract the truncate logic, to clean things up, and avoid the repetition.

```
function truncateFilename (filename) {
  if(filename.length > 14) {
    return filename.substring(0, 14) + "...";
  }
  return filename;
}
```

And since you've stuck to a naming convention for the elements you want to display the filenames, you can create a function to set up your event handling:

```
function addFileSelectHandler(inputClass) {
  $(inputClass).on("fileselect", function (event, filename) {
    $(inputClass + "-name").text(truncateFilename(filename));
  });
}

addFileSelectHandler(".compliance-guide");
addFileSelectHandler(".compliance-other");
addFileSelectHandler(".agreement-file");
```

Other notes:

- Don't use `.html()` when you're just setting plain text strings; use `.text()` (as seen above)
- Don't use classes to identify unique elements; use IDs. It's what they're for.
- CSS has a `text-overflow` rule that'll auto-truncate text if it overflows - no need for JavaScript at all, and no need for a hard-coded length of 14. As always, letter-count has little to do with how much space it takes to display; "m"s take up a lot more space than "i"s (if you're using a non-monospaced font).

Also, you could choose to handle all of this in the generic `$(:file).on("change",..` function. Instead of using specific classes on the elements that should show a filename, you could use a `data-input` attribute to link them to a file input.

For instance, you could have this markup:

```
<input type="file" id="some-file">
<span class="filename" data-input="some-file"></span>

<input type="file" id="some-other-file">
<span class="filename" data-input="some-other-file"></span>
```

And this JS:

```
$(document).on('change', ':file', function () {
  var input = $(this),
      filename = input.val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/g, '');

  $(".filename[data-input='" + this.id + "']").text(filename);

  // you can still trigger your custom event, if you want
  // input.trigger('fileselect', [filename]);
});
```

That'll automatically show the filename, provided there's an element to show it. If there's no element, well, then it's not shown.

Comment: What a wonderful answer. Insightful, informative, articulate and extremely helpful - thank you so much for your time! Bit of a rookie error re the use of id's I shouldn't have missed that. Are there any cross browser issues regarding your feedback I should be aware of?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor Thanks. And no, I can't think of any browser issues here. If it runs jQuery to begin with, it should run this just fine. But test it thoroughly regardless; I've been wrong before.

Comment: Great just doing some testing now - seems to be ok. Thanks again.